# Formula for underdiversification

Tags: diversification

I'm trying to develop a study which links a person's demographic and social characteristics to a tendency to under diversify their portfolio. So far I was accounting for risk aversion and just going the divide by n method, but is there a more specific way to know if a person is under diversified?

For context, in the study I give participants 3 assets, a low risk bond, moderate risk fund and high risk stock, and ask them to split assets between the three classes. This happens over 3 trading periods, and I have full control over the return of the asset

Sorry if this question isn't very specific.. is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

A variant of the [Herfindahl-Hirschman index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herfindahl%E2%80%93Hirschman_Index), specifically its inverse, is probably the most widely used for this sort of thing.  It's a measure of portfolio or market concentration, where an equally-weighted portfolio (most diversified) has an effective sample size equal to the number of assets.  It's a cousin of the Gini coefficient used a lot in income inequality research.

Calculated as follows, where $w_i$ are holding weights:

$effSS = \frac{1}{\sum_{i}w_i^2}$

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read John Y. Cambell AFA presidential address, namely section III of his paper: https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/campbell/files/householdfinance_jof_2006.pdf

There are few ways of measuring underdiversification, few of them are outlined in the paper above but I guess the most obvious is the first one they mention:

> We adopt the perspective that systematic risk is compensated and
>   idiosyncratic risk is not, so that taking idiosyncratic risk is an
>   investment mistake.

So, you can use the amount of idiosyncratic risk as a proxy for underdiversification.